# Перехват изменения input кроме удаления символов

Tags: jquery

Здравствуйте,

При таком назначении обрабатываются абсолютно все изменения.

```js
$(document).load(function() {
  $("#in").on('change paste keyup', function() {
    //....
  });
});
```

Как заставить скрипт игнорировать любые виды удаления символов из input (backspace, delete, ctrl+x)?

Comment: Проверять в обработчике нажатые кнопки, и не перехватывать их если это backspace И т.д.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var value;
    $("#in").on('change paste keyup', function(e) {
        if(e.keyCode == 46) {
            console.log('ckick delete');
        }
        if(e.keyCode == 8) {
            console.log('ckick backspace');
        }
        console.log(e.keyCode);

        if($(this)[0].value.length < value.length) {
            console.log($(this)[0].value.length);
        }
        value = $(this)[0].value;
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fliginskih/ysww100g/

Можно считывать коды кнопок ([тут коды](http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes)), плюс можно отслеживать изменения параметра `value` и сравнивать его с предыдущим.